# How to move text in a Canvas with a button that calls the function to make the text appear in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, javascript-objects

I have a canvas in my HTML `id="myCanvas"` and a button when clicked calls this function:

```
function writeCanvas(){
     var can = document.getElementById("myCanvas");    
     var ctx = can.getContext("2d"); 
     var xPos = 50;
     var yPos = 50;

     window.addEventListener('click', moveIt, true);

     ctx.fillStyle= "red";
     ctx.font = "30px Arial";
     ctx.fillText("Kunal Sharma", xPos, yPos); 
}
```

How do I make it so that each time the button is clicked the text moves right or down?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example:

```html
<button onclick="drawText()">Move Text</button><br>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>

<script>
  var can = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
  var xPos = 10;
  var yPos = 20;

  function drawText() {
    xPos += 10 
    yPos += 10 
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 999, 999)
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("Kunal Sharma", xPos, yPos);
  }
  drawText()
</script>
```

The idea is to change the xPos & yPos inside the function.
And we clear and redraw on every call to drawText.

Comment: Yeah but I want the on click to be from a button in my HTML.

Comment: Easy we just add a button `<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>`... see my addition on the code